# while running oracle form,FRM-91145: fatal error in runtime process: missing serverArgs parameter is displayed

Tags: oracle12c, oracleforms

I have installed Oracle Database 12c with formsapp 12.2.1. I have configured webconfig.cfg and default.env. Forms path is added correctly but this error is still there. In base.htm, there is no param named as serverArgs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you messed up the default configuration.  Cleanup and reinstall then create a new WLS Domain.  Do not make any changes without first testing the basics first.  Also, you cannot edit formsweb.cfg, default.env, or many other config files in a text editor.  You must make changes from within Fusion Middleware Control.